# Render fileName using image-picker in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am using react-native-image-picker I want to render the fileName which I got in it's response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store what you want to show on screen in your component state and render according to that

Answer (score 0):

```
static launchImageLibrary(options?, callback)
```

It is contained in the `callback value` of the module function.

[image: response]